# Icons in dired in Emacs (on Mac or Linux)

Tags: emacs, icons, dired

I'd like to have dired show a little icon next to each file, similar to what you'd see in "list" or "details" view on a graphical file browser. Someone posted a similar question but the only answer was for Windows only; I want to be able to do this on Linux or Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the sad answer is "no, unless you do some extensive hacking of the dired-mode source code".

Comment: This is no longer true nowadays. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think "bignose" is right, you would not be able to do that easily.  But check out [Dired+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus).  It can colorize files by type so you can get *some* visual feedback on your dired buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I too would like to be able to do this.  More generally, I would like GNU Emacs to support display of MS Windows icons (icon images).  I would use them (optionally) in [***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) (in buffer `*Completions*`) and [***Bookmark+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus), as well as in [***Dired+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/DiredPlus), to provide simple feedback about the file types (and associated Windows applications).

Alas, I haven't been able to interest Emacs Dev (so far). At least we have image support now in general (so you can optionally see thumbnails in `*Completions*`, for example).

Comment: Maybe you are interested in [this](http://www.ring.gr.jp/archives/elisp/gohome/junk/dired-dispicon.el)?

Comment: @xuhdev: Thanks. I had already looked at that back in 2011. It requires a couple of other libraries, and it seems not to be for MS Windows. But I haven't really looked into it much.

Comment: The extension is actually for Windows only -- you can look into its comments.

Comment: As you pointed out in the other question, the link to the sources is broken.

Comment: It turns out that the link is not stable... I can open it right now.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux and MacOS, use [dired-icon](https://gitlab.com/xuhdev/dired-icon).

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the extension.